# Transformer heating

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I have difficulty grasping the concept of transformer heating and the overall effect on voltage, current and magnetic induction. I assume that for a transformer to heat up the current should increase as H = I2RT. So the volatge in the secondary coil should drop.

But from what I came across internet it seems that the volatge drop in the secondary coil is not significant when discussing transformer losses. This made me think that perhaps it is due to the load resistance that the heat is produced and thus it should be the current in the which should decrease and voltage increase.

And for the third scenario, if current is decreased then magnetic induction should decrease ( oppose the cause producing it) and voltage should also decrease.

My question is what actually happens to the voltage, current and magnetic induction when a transformer is heated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the primary coil of a transformer is heated by ohmic losses in its wire, its DC resistance goes up and so the current flowing through it goes down. This weakens its magnetic field and causes the current induced in the secondary to decrease. When the secondary gets hot because of ohmic heating, its resistance goes up too and the current flowing through it decreases even more.